# Get all dependent packages of Go inside docker

Tags: docker, go

I can get all my dependent packages when I do the following:

```
$ cd myrepo
$ go get -d ./...
```

But what is the best way to do this in docker? I don't want all the repo's inside my docker-app so I'm searching for a way to execute this inside a docker container to some volume (or something like that) and reuse it.

I was thinking about something like.
Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.8

WORKDIR /app
ADD ./src
```

Build image

```
$ docker build -t myapp .

$ docker run myapp go get -d ./...
```

How can I reuse the dependencies without pulling/downloading them every time? I want them in a sort of volume. I know docker volumes a bit but I don't know how to use it in this case.

Comment: you use RUN and install dependencies in  dockerfile. Docker caches a layer (which contains dependencies) and does not pull it every time as long as it exists on your system( it exists unless you remove image using docker rmi)

Comment: @Vasif isn't my image not going to be huge then? (there are a lot of dependent repos)

Comment: Yes the image is going to be huge. But, if you do not have it in image.. every time your container gets deleted( say for update purpose) you will need to place all the dependencies into the image back again.. Also, I feel having dependencies within the container is a core principle. Coz, well, containers are solution to provide isolated run time environment. You probably won't want to cut edges there.. what's the size if I may ask?

Comment: The best way to reduce the size, is building a second image with only the compiled executable with the builder pattern https://blog.alexellis.io/mutli-stage-docker-builds/

Comment: @Julian I suggest you should post your comment as answer - I would also mention the official docs at https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use the builder pattern.
In the first image you download all the dependencies and build the executable.
In the second you copy the executable into a new image. You can use the scratch image as a base, but alpine is maybe better because it is also small but provides a shell and a packet manager for something like certificates for https.

If you first copy the sources and the install the dependencies, they will be downloaded with every source change, so it ist better to use something like go dep. With it you can copy the Gopkg file, install your dependencies and then copy the sources.

Official article https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/
and in more detail
https://blog.alexellis.io/mutli-stage-docker-builds/